# Title partially cut off when using custom command

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using a Tikz poster for a project. I am using a custom command `\fadingtext` for a gradient effect. when I use `\title{ProjectTitle}`, the compiled result is a standard title. But when I use `\title{\fadingtext{ProjectTitle}}` gets partially cut off at the top. I have tried displacing the title but it remains unaffected. The font also changes when using this command.

```latex
\documentclass[17pt,a2paper,portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\definecolor{UniBlue}{HTML}{0053A1}
\definecolor{CW2LightPink}{HTML}{FF3AB7}
\definecolor{CW2DarkPink}{HTML}{A00066}

\newcommand\fadingtext[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name = fading letter]
    \node[text = transparent!0, inner xsep = 0pt, outer xsep = 0pt] {#2};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (textnode.base)]
    \node[inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt] (textnode) {\phantom{#2}}; 
    \shade[path fading = fading letter, fading text, #1, fit fading = false]
    (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);% 
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}

\tikzset{fading text/.style = {left color = CW2LightPink, right color  = CW2DarkPink}}

\title{\fadingtext{Modelling a Tennis Ball}}
%\title{Modelling a Tennis Ball}
\author{JKS}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fit fading=false` prevents scaling of the fading, but it will still be translated. Here I use a hack to align the centers by adding an extra circle `\draw[transparent!100] (0,0) circle[radius=10];`. I will be happy to learn other ways.

```
\documentclass[17pt,a2paper,portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\newcommand\fadingtext[2][]{%
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fading letter]
\node[transparent!0, anchor=base] {#2};
\draw[transparent!100] (0,0) circle[radius=10];
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node[anchor=base, inner sep=0] (textnode) {\phantom{#2}}; 
\draw[path fading=fading letter, fading text, #1, fit fading=false] (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);% 
\end{tikzpicture}% 
}

\tikzset{fading text/.style = {left color=red, right color=green}}
\title{\fadingtext{Modelling a Tennis Ball}}
%\title{Modelling a Tennis Ball}
\author{JKS}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Title of page with fading colors]

Edit: Better than drawing the circle, is to use it as a bounding box:

```
\useasboundingbox (0,0) circle[radius=10];
```